# Select Min ID in a partition - MSSQL t-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, partition-by, over-clause

I would like to select the minimum ID of a partition.  Kind of like how dense_rank works I'd like a unique number associated with each paritition, but I'd like that numbber to be the minimum primary key within the partition.  Here is an example of what I'm after.

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;  
GO  
SELECT '276 or 289 depending on what partition' as 'Min_BusinessEntityID'
  ,s.BusinessEntityID
  ,p.LastName
  ,s.SalesYTD
  ,a.PostalCode
 FROM Sales.SalesPerson AS s   
INNER JOIN Person.Person AS p   
    ON s.BusinessEntityID = p.BusinessEntityID  
INNER JOIN Person.Address AS a   
    ON a.AddressID = p.BusinessEntityID  
WHERE TerritoryID IS NOT NULL   
AND SalesYTD <> 0  
ORDER BY PostalCode, SalesYTD DESC
```

[Result Set Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNpqL.png)

Comment: if it's only going to be 2 values, then a `CASE WHEN` statement would probably be easier than one of the window functions

Comment: It will often be thousands of values in my real world implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL Server [MIN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/min-transact-sql) commands accepts the OVER() clause:

```
SELECT MIN(s.BusinessEntityID) OVER (PARTITION BY TerritoryID) AS Min_BusinessEntityID
FROM ...
```